# How to get data from ViewModel in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have:

```
public class ViewCustomerViewModel
{
    public Customer CustomerInfo { get; set; }
    public static string baseUrl = "https://xxxx/Customers/";
    public ViewCustomerViewModel()
    {
        CheckUserinfo();
    }
    public async void CheckUserinfo()
    {
        .....
        var url = baseUrl;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", xxx);
        string jsonStr = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(jsonStr);

        CustomerInfo = res;
    }
}
```

`CustomerInfo` returns oke

[image]

I have PageOne.xaml

```
<ContentPage ...>
  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <locals:ViewCustomerViewModel/>
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>
  <ContentPage.Content>
     
      <Label Text={Binding xxxx} />

  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

PageOne.xaml.cs

This is how I get the data to Binding:

```
public Customer CustomerInfo { get; set; }
public PageOne()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new ViewCustomerViewModel();
}
```

However: in PageOne.xaml page when I <Label Text={Binding xxxx} /> ---> Binding xxxx, I get no value of Customer class.

[image]

I was doing something wrong. Please help me how can I display `CustomerInfo` results. Thank you

**Update**

PageOne.xaml

```
<ContentPage ...>      
  <ContentPage.Content>
     
      <Label Text={Binding xxxx} />

  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: 1) you are declaring the VM in both the XAML and the code, pick one or the other, not both, 2) you are calling async methods from the constructor

Comment: I tried again and removed <ContentPage.BindingContext> from PageOne.xaml. Change public async void CheckUserinfo() ---> public void CheckUserinfo(). But I still get the same error

Comment: Can you describe it clearly with your answer? I think it's easier for me to learn

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when the constructor completes, the instance is still being asynchronously initialized, and there isn’t an obvious way to determine when the asynchronous initialization has completed.

Instead of calling from the constructor, do it from the page's `OnAppearing` method, which you can make async.

Or you could change your viewmodel,make a [Factory Pattern](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) for it.From the link,there are several methods you could refer to.