# How to Binding Result from ViewModel in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have 1 question here: [How to get data from ViewModel in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68966887/how-to-get-data-from-viewmodel-in-xamarin), however I still haven't solved the problem. I created a new post with some changes.

I have:

1. PageOne.xaml

   ```
    <StackLayout>
         <RefreshView x:DataType="locals:ViewCustomerViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadUserinfoCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}">
              <Label Text="{Binding Customer.Address}" />
         </RefreshView>
    </StackLayout>
   ```
2. PageOne.xaml.cs

   ```
     ViewCustomerViewModel viewCustomerViewModel;
     public Customer CustomerGet { get; set; }
     public PageOne()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewCustomerViewModel = new ViewCustomerViewModel();
        viewCustomerViewModel.OnAppearing();
     }
   ```
3. Class Customer

   ```
    public class Customer
    {
       public string Address{ get; set; }
       ........
    }
   ```
4. ViewCustomerViewModel

   ```
    public class ViewCustomerViewModel:BaseCustomerViewModel
    {
       ApiServiceUserinfo apiServiceUserinfo = new ApiServiceUserinfo();
       public Command LoadUserinfoCommand { get; }
       public ObservableCollection<Customer> CustomerInfos { get; set; }
       public ViewCustomerViewModel()
       {
          LoadUserinfoCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadUserinfoCommand());
          CustomerInfos = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
       }

       public void OnAppearing()
       {
          IsBusy = true;
       }

       async Task ExecuteLoadUserinfoCommand()
       {
          string userget = "1";

          IsBusy = true;

          try
          {
            CustomerInfos.Clear();
            var customerList = await apiServiceUserinfo.GetCustomersInfo(userget);
            CustomerInfos.Add(customerList);
          }
          catch (Exception)
          {
            throw;
          }
          finally
          {
            IsBusy = false;
          }
       }
    }
   ```

And I got the result `CustomerInfos.Add(customerList);`

[image]

However `<Label Text="{Binding Customer.Address}" />` does not get results

Please help me again clearly in the answer. Thank you.

**Update**

4. ViewCustomerViewModel

   ```
    public class ViewCustomerViewModel:BaseCustomerViewModel
    {
       ApiServiceUserinfo apiServiceUserinfo = new ApiServiceUserinfo();
       public Command LoadUserinfoCommand { get; set;}

       public Customer CustomerGets { get; set;}--> update

       public ViewCustomerViewModel()
       {
          LoadUserinfoCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadUserinfoCommand());
          //CustomerGets = new Customer();
       }

       public void OnAppearing()
       {
          IsBusy = true;
       }

       async Task ExecuteLoadUserinfoCommand()
       {
          string userget = "1";

          IsBusy = true;

          try
          {
            var customerList = await apiServiceUserinfo.GetCustomersInfo(userget);
            CustomerGets = customerList;
          }
          catch (Exception)
          {
            throw;
          }
          finally
          {
            IsBusy = false;
          }
       }
    }
   ```

[image]

1. PageOne.xaml

   ```
   <StackLayout>
      <RefreshView x:DataType="locals:ViewCustomerViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadUserinfoCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}">
          <Label Text="{Binding CustomerGets.Address}" />
      </RefreshView>
   </StackLayout>
   ```

Comment: `{Binding Customer.Address}` your VM does not have a property named `Customer`.

Comment: I updated: public Customer CustomerGet { get; set; } in ViewCustomerViewModel, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you update the binding to use `CustomerGet`?   Where is `CustomerGet` assigned any values?  If your VM represents data for a single customer, why do you have an `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: I removed the ObservableCollection in the update, however it still doesn't work.

Comment: `CustomerGets` is not calling PropertyChanged in its setter, so the UI is not update.  You can try setting the BindingContext **after** the data is loaded to avoid this

Comment: How can I do that, can you post it in the reply? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to call the `OnPropertyChanged` method to notify the change in `setter` method of the property .

```
private Customer customerGets;
public Customer CustomerGets { 
  get { return customerGets; }
  set { 
          customerGets = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged();     //the method is declared in BaseCustomerViewModel 
      }
}
```

Ensure that `BaseCustomerViewModel` has implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` , something like that

```
 public class BaseCustomerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```